# How to enable a button after a certain button is clicked?

Tags: android, user-interface

Here is the scenario : I have a gui which contains two buttons.Now is there any way by which second button is clickable only after first button is clicked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say you have activity with two buttons defined in the xml layout : button1 and button2

in activity onCreate method write:

```
button2.setEnabled(false);
```

In the in click listener of first button write

```
button2.setEnabled(true);
```

so finally 
in onCreate method of the activity we have

```
button2.setEnabled(false);

private OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      button2.setEnabled(true);
    }
};

button1.setOnClickListener(l);
```

Comment: It's not working.Do I have to declare button2.setEnabled(true) in onClick() or outside that ?

Comment: @dark_shadow i have just edited it... want some more? i can write the whole onCreate method here